# Page refreshes during JQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

For some reason when this JQuery call is made the page refreshes. I was lead to believe that a `return false;` at the end of a JQuery function would cause the page not to reload, but apparently this is not the case? Here is my stripped down code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".vote").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I click on the vote button the page is refreshed. I know that this code is being called because if I replace `return false` with `alert('asdf');` the alert appears.

Comment: are the .vote elements inside a form tag?

Comment: What's **inside** the "vote" button? (And is it a `<button>` or an `<input type='button'>` ?

Comment: If you're using `type="submit"` on the button try using `type="button"`

Comment: post your code for vote html..i mean vote might be a class name to some html right

Comment: `<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $rowID; ?>" name="up"><div class="upvote" id="upvote<?php echo $rowID; ?>" style=<?php echo "$upvote"; ?>></div></a>`

Comment: @Overstock Flaw: I think it might be a problem, that your attribute `href` of the `a.vote` element is empty. Could you try it with a value of `#`? Another possible source of the problem that I haven't seen mentioned yet: Is the element `a.vote` in a block that is loaded dynamically with an Ajax-request? If that's the case, binding event handlers to elements on `domready` will not bind to elements that are yet to be loaded via Ajax. In that case, the easiest way to account for that would be to use `jQuery.live()` bind the event handlers. See [API Docs - live()](http://api.jquery.com/live)

Answer (score 0):

Often when you want to prevent a link from being followed or a form from submitting, you want to tell the event to preventDefault():

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: but he is doing return false, which will do e.preventDefault and stopPropogatoin..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".vote").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the page is still refreshing. I tried appending `return false;` to the end as well and still no good. Any ideas?

Comment: my guess is that you have an error somewhere else in your javascript - open up the page in firefox and open up the errors panel to see if some other line throws an error. Either doing return false or preventDefault SHOULD take care of it, but if there's an error elsewhere, your whole chunk of JS will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `div` in an `a`: `div` is block-level element, `a` is inline, and HTML does not allow block elements inside inline elements. Browsers will try to automatically correct this by rearranging your DOM tree somehow (for example, `<a><div></div></a>` might end up as `<a></a><div><a></a></div><a></a>`); which leads to all sort of funny behavior. In Firefox you can use 'view selection source' (or, of course, Firebug) to check what happened.